When do we have $\bigoplus_{i + j = n} R^i f_* \mathbb{Q}_\ell \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_\ell} R^j g_* \mathbb{Q}_\ell \cong R^{i + j} h_* \mathbb{Q}_\ell$?
Milne, Étale Cohomology, theorem 8.5 states the following version of the Künneth formula (in slightly greater generality). Let $\Lambda$ be a finite commutative ring. Let $X, Y, S$ be schemes with $S$ quasi-compact, and let $f: X \to S$, $g: Y \to S$ be proper morphisms. Let $p: X \times_S Y \to X$, $q: X \times_S Y \to Y$ be the projections, and $h = f \circ p$. Let $F$ and $G$ be sheaves of $\Lambda$-modules on $X_{\acute{e}t}$ and $Y_{\acute{e} t}$, respectively, with $F$ flat. Define $F \boxtimes G$ to be $p^* F \otimes_\Lambda q^* G$. Then there is a canonical quasi-isomorphism $R f_* F \otimes_\Lambda R g_* G \cong R h_* (F \boxtimes G)$. If, moreover, $R^r f_* F$ is flat for all $r \ge 0$, then $\bigoplus\limits_{i + j = n} R^i f_* F \otimes_\Lambda R^j g_* G \cong R^{i + j}h_*(F \boxtimes G)$.
My question is the extent to which the latter isomorphism holds with $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ or $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ coefficients. Specifically, if $R^r f_* \underline{\mathbb{Z} / \ell^s \mathbb{Z}}$ is flat as a sheaf of $\mathbb{Z} / \ell^s \mathbb{Z}$-modules for all $r, s \ge 0$ (where $\underline{\mathbb{Z} / \ell^s \mathbb{Z}}$ is a constant sheaf), is there an isomorphism $\bigoplus\limits_{i + j = n} R^i f_* \mathbb{Z}_\ell \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_\ell} R^j g_* \mathbb{Z}_\ell \cong R^{i + j}h_* \mathbb{Z}_\ell$? I think this is probably true and straightforward (if tedious) to work out from what is in Milne. It should simply follow from compatibility of the isomorphism in Milne with the inverse system of maps $R^r f_* \underline{\mathbb{Z} / \ell^{s+1} \mathbb{Z}} \to R^r f_* \underline{\mathbb{Z} / \ell^{s} \mathbb{Z}}$. I would much prefer to have a reference, though.

Should it be $R^n$, not $R^{i + j}$, on the right-hand side?

The defining definition of $\ell$-adic sheaves is that the operator $(-)\otimes^L\mathbb{Z}/\ell$ detects isomorphisms (in the derived category). Since this operator commutes with everything, any formula, formulated using total derived functors, proven with $\Lambda$-linear coefficients, with $\Lambda$ of characteristic (a power of) $\ell$, implies right away its analogous formula with $\mathbb{Z}\ell$-linear coeffcients. Tensoring by $\mathbb{Q}$ yields the $\mathbb{Q}\ell$-linear version as well.

@D.-C.Cisinski Thank you for this deep observation.

I meant ``The defining property of...''
